# Custom CSS and Sharepoint online

Tags: html, css, dom, office365, sharepoint-online

I was researching for supported and unsupported customization and custom CSS approaches that can be used in sharepoint online for branding, however due to microsoft's confusing and vague articles it is very hard to get clarification.

I was researching on applying custom CSS through alternate CSS in publishing site and looking into this article :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/portal-branding

In this article there one point under "General Principles" , this point is ambiguous/vague and doesn't give clarification in detail.

General Principles

The following general principles should be considered when branding portals in an SharePoint Online environment:

The SharePoint Online service is constantly improving. Updates provisioned to the service may affect DOM structure of out of the box pages, and the content of out of the box files (for example, master pages). Developers must keep this in mind and should not rely on unsupported customization approaches (for example, position of specific element in DOM structure of the page).

In above point it mentions : Developers must keep this in mind and should not rely on unsupported customization approaches (for example, position of specific element in DOM structure of the page). -- What does this really mean ? Does this apply to Custom CSS applied through alternate CSS URL only on few web part pages and CSS only applies to web part zones and OOTB web parts within.

Can someone clarify this ? I need expert opinion. Does above statement only apply to Office 365 bar DOM and it's CSS or DOM of OOTB web part page ? If so then how ? Could someone please provide example ? I have written custom CSS and applied through alternate CSS url , it mostly changes appearance of web part zones and OOTB list view web parts within them (like color, width, bigger fonts etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this relates to SharePoint specifically, or even the utilisation of an external CSS stylesheet. Let's break down the language for a second:

> "Developers [...] should not rely on [...] position of specific element in DOM structure of the page"

It is my belief that Microsoft are referring to using CSS (or even JavaScript) to target elements based on the DOM structure, rather than element ID or class. Consider `p + div` (which targets any `<div>` element that immediately proceeds a `<p>` element).

In this situation, it works:

```css
p + div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Text</p>
<div id="div">More text</div>
```

In this situation, it does not:

```css
p + div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Text</p>
<a>Link</a>
<div id="div">More text</div>
```

All I did was move the `#div` element's position in the DOM, and suddenly my selector no longer worked. I believe this is the danger that Microsoft is alluding to.

As such, it would be far 'safer' to target the desired element **directly**, with `#` to **[select the ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors)**:

```css
#div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Text</p>
<a>Link</a>
<div id="div">More text</div>
```

Obviously there will be situations where you won't **have** an ID for an element, though you can rely on **[class selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)**, **[attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)**, or even **[type selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors)**. Work with **[specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)**, and adapt to suit, aiming to avoid context as much as possible.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Is this considered as positioning in DOM :   .tableCol-75 .tableCol-33 thead ? In most of the scenarios I need to reduce scope of type selectors. Can we reduce scope of type selectors in the way I mentioned ?

Comment: I would have shown generated DOM and CSS that I applied but I am not sure how do I copy generated DOM and display here

Comment: Your first point is open to debate; `tableCol-33` would have to be a **child** of `tableCol-75`. That means that if you made it a **sibling** instead, it wouldn't work. That's not to say that's a bad selector though! What if you have **two** classes `tableCol-75` (one a child of `tableCol-33`, and one a sibling), and **only** want to target the child? Then you have the perfect selector. You can use `>` to denote a **direct** child. To target both, you would just use `tableCol-33` directly. To enter code here, simply click on the code icon (next to the picture) when editing your question :)

Comment: Yes tableCol-33 is child of tableCol-75, what I have done is I found classes of rendered HTML and then overwritten CSS for those classes to give it custom look. FYI I am not generating any HTML here. I can see DOM in developer tool bar and associated styles but not sure how do I copy DOM and associated styles here.

Comment: That sounds like the right way to go about things; if you're working with a CMS or back-end script that's generating its own HTML, it's best to just overwrite their code with [**greater specificity**](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). To post HTML from your site to StackOverflow you would view the source with `CTRL` + `U` and manually copy-paste the relevant segments to an [**edit of your question**](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Though you're doing things the right way, and seem to have resolved your issue.